# Finding Var(XYZ)

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

> Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be independent and identically distributed random
>   variables with mean = 1 and variance = 2. Find $Var(XYZ)$.

$Var(XYZ)$

$= E((XYZ)^2) - (E(XYZ))^2$

$= E(X^2Y^2Z^2) - (E(XYZ))^2$

$= E(X^2)E(Y^2)E(Z^2) -(E(X)E(Y)E(Z))^2$ since $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are independent.

$= E(X^2)E(Y^2)E(Z^2) -(1\cdot1\cdot1)^2$

$= E(X^2)E(Y^2)E(Z^2) - 1$

$=$ ..... ?

> $= 26$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
2=\text{Var}(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2=EX^2-1
$$
Thus
$$
EX^2=EY^2=EZ^2=3
$$
since $X,Y,Z$ are identical in distribution.

Comment: Whoaaaaa, I wouldn've never figured that out on a test!

Comment: So for questions like these, I should fully write out what they've given us in equation form and try to derive what I need, if possible?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just memorize whenever we're given $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$, we can find $E(X^2)$ with the definition of $Var(X)$